# Visual studio unit test passing then failing immediately with no changes to code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I quite new to C# and have created a unit test project with two tests. However, I'm getting a weird result in one of the tests.

When i click "Run all tests", the test fails. But when i immediately click "Run Failed tests", the test passes.

What could the problem be please?

Here is the test method

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void GetFiles_WithNoIgnoreValueProvided_ReturnsAllFiles()
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\myDocs\Desktop\New folder";
        var thefiles = Filer.GetFiles(path) as List<string>;

        Assert.AreEqual(3, thefiles.Count);
    }
```

**EDIT**
The message on test failure is "Test Failed - Assert.Areequal failed. Expected: 3 Actual 2.

[image: Strange test result]

EDIT TWO:
Heres My Filer class. I am trying to create a static class that can be used to return all files in a directory (and any subdirectories recursively)

```
 public static class Filer
{
    private static List<string> ignorethesefiles;
    private static List<string> thefiles;


    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, IEnumerable<string> ignorefilescontaining = null)
    {
        if (ignorefilescontaining !=null)
        {
            ignorethesefiles = new List<string>(); ignorethesefiles.AddRange(ignorefilescontaining);
        }
        else
        {
            ignorethesefiles = new List<string>() { "@" };

        }

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            // This path is a file
            ProcessFile(path, ref thefiles);
        }


        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            // This path is a directory
            //if (ignorethesefiles.Count > 0)
            //{

            ProcessDirectory(path, ref thefiles, ref ignorethesefiles);


        }

        return thefiles;

    }

    private static void ProcessDirectory(string path, ref List<string> thefiles, ref List<string> ignorethesefiles)
    {

        //Process files in the directory
        IEnumerable<string> filesindir = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (var filename in filesindir)
        {
            //  if (ignorefilescontaining != string.Empty)
          //  if (ignorethesefiles.Count > 0)
           // {
                if (!ignorethesefiles.Any(s=>filename.Contains(s)))
                {
                    ProcessFile(filename, ref thefiles);
                }
             // ProcessFile(filename, ref thefiles);

           // }
        }

        //Recurse subdirectories
        IEnumerable<string> subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (var sub in subdirectories)
        {
            ProcessDirectory(sub, ref thefiles, ref ignorethesefiles);
        }

    }

    private static void ProcessFile(string path, ref List<string> thefiles)
    {
        if (thefiles == null)
        {
            thefiles = new List<string>();
            thefiles.Add(path);
        }
        else
        {
            thefiles.Add(path);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Credit to @Matthewwatson for the following improvement (i think :) ) its certainly less verbose:

```
    public static class SOFinder
{
    public static IEnumerable<string>GetListOfFiles(string path,string pattern, SearchOption searchoption)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return files;
    }
}
```

Now reading up on LINQ to see how i can filter the result to produce a list that DOES NOT contain a given string. Or can someone give me a hint please?

Will also look to mock the file system then test again and update on the result. cheers

cheers

Comment: What error does the output have, or what is the actual file count on the fail?

Comment: What does the unit test fail with? Is there an exception? Looks like it might be a race condition with resources not being released.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the response guys. ive added the failure message. cheers

Comment: Perhaps there's a bug in `Filer.GetFiles()` where it's not closing/disposing/cleaning up something, so something is still open when the next test runs and therefore it fails.

Comment: Also, you might want to re-consider a unit test like this, you're basically testing framework code (i.e. not yours) and it's not advisable.

Comment: The unit test *itself* isn't broken.  Clearly `Filer.GetFiles` is returning inconsistent results.  Sounds like you have some debugging to do.

Comment: Also when you are doing unit tests, you have to test your code. Not the .NET Code. Here now you are depending on file system. You have to Mock the file system in order to test your code. If not you are not doing proper unit tests.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ive now added the code i'm trying to test.cheers

Comment: whats the point of this test? Try to mock away the actual calls to system to be independent and can have stable unit tests.

Comment: @vidstige - thanks, im still learning and will read up on mocking.

Comment: The file on disc might be in use the second time you run your test. You should really mock dependecies like these.

Comment: [nitpick] It's probably stubbing rather than mocking you need here.

Comment: Incidentally, is there a reason you can't use [`public static Enumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to recursively enumerate the files?

Comment: @MatthewWatson - hi, i was not aware of that method at all! Thanks for the tip. Ill try that too :)

Comment: Try only running the odd test, not all. Does it fail then? If not then it's because your other test is changing the directory or using it preventing access. You may have a test dependency

Comment: RE your latest edit: You should use `EnumerateFiles()` rather than `GetFiles()`, and you can filter with `files.Where(filename => !listToIgnore.Contains(Path.GetFileName(filename)));`

Answer (score 0):

This can often happen because of a Remnant from the old test. if the unit test depends on something not existing, but the old Unit Test left something behind, it can have an issue. it really depends on the error message, which seems to be an inequality error. This could mean that something is creating a file/folder which collides with another file/folder in that directory. I would stick a breakpoint on the Unit Test and step into it. When the error gets thrown (you'll get a more detailed error), just read the message and you should get an explanation

Comment: thanks for your response. currently trying to simplify the method as suggested by @Matthewwatson above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a test dependency. Your other test is affecting the result of your failing test. I bet the other test looks at the same directory, it is then locking/removing a file, your other test is trying to look in the same directory but can't add one of the files because the other test has opened it.

Comment: hi, yes both tests are looking at the same directory. I will refactor and update.cheers